# Will AMP affect rankings for non-mobile traffic?

Tags: ranking, amp

I've been researching [accelerated mobile pages](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2016/01/amp-error-report-preview-in-search.html)(AMP) for my e-commerce website. My traffic is a small percentage mobile (but it is growing). I'm not sure it is worth implementing AMP for my website in the near future *unless* it affects ranking for the non-AMP pages of my site.

Will implementing AMP have some sort of positive correlation on the non-mobile search ranking? How about in the short term?

Comment: I would not think so. Mobile and Desktop search result sets go through many similar filters, however, clearly mobile is handled differently with a different set of filters in a final ranking algorithm for mobile searches. The two shall never meet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question depends on your SEO strategy. Companies that have a thorough organic strategy have content mapping, where they produce digestible content for consumers in each stage of the "buyer's journey."

If you push out relevant/engaging/high quality content regularly, then AMP might be worth your time. It would get more eyeballs on your brand/domain which could translate into consumers remembering that your website is a source for them to get content related to their interests, which in turn could translate into more organic conversions/lead gen.

Another thing to consider is that the more people start coming to your site for content and engaging with it, spending more time on site, sharing content, etc, the more Google will value your page and the higher in the SERP you will go. This could also be calculated as "we pushed out x amount of AMP content, saw X% lift in traffic which led to X# more conversions which translated to X$."

If consumable content isn't a big part of your strategy, then I wouldn't necessarily bother. The ROI most likely wouldn't be very high and you could get more value focusing your efforts elsewhere.

AMP, to me, is more for news sources, blogs, or sites that focus on content (e.g. someone like Buzzfeed).